# Obtaining all properties in a class marked with an attibute

Tags: c#, attributes

I have produced a custom attribute which simply marks a classes property as being the 'display name'. What I would like to do is find the property within a given class which has been marked with my attribute. As far as I know, the only way I can do this is to loop through each property (via reflection) and check what attributes it has assigned. Is there any easier/quicker way than this?

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in myClassProperties)
{
  //Get the alias attributes.
  object[] attr=
  property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayField), true);

  if(attr.Count() > 0)
  {
   // This is a display field!
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Since you have an array, you should use `attr.Length` rather than `attr.Count()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's *slightly* simpler than checking all its attributes to find the one you want - you can ask any member whether it *has* a particular attribute using [`IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.isdefined.aspx):

```
var properties = type.GetProperties()
                     .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(MyAttribute), false));
```

Obviously you can cache that result on a per-type basis if you're going to use it multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

> As far as I know, the only way I can do this is to loop through each property (via reflection) and check what attributes it has assigned.

That's exactly the way to do it. Attributes are metadata which is baked into the assembly at compile time. In order to access them at runtime you need Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

the only quicker way that I'm aware of is to create a dictionary either statically or in a singleton... so that subsequent visits are faster.  I do this caching sometimes, but I do exactly as you outline above for the retrieve attribute functionality.